# How to get single last record with a particular id in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, greatest-n-per-group

Here i have 2 tables. First one is **customer** and second on is **membership**

Now i just want to get a single last record with a particular `customer_id` from these jioned table(customer and membership).

**Here is my customer table structure**

[image]

**Here is my membership table structure and desired latest inserted rows**

[image]

Here i've tried a code myself

```
    $results="";
        $this->db->select('customer.*,membership.*');
        $this->db->from('customer');
        $this->db->join('membership', 'customer.id = membership.customer_id', 'left'); 
       /* $this->db->order_by('membership.id','DESC');
        $this->db->limit('1');*/
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $query->result_array();


$todayDate =  date("d-m-Y"); 
foreach ($data as $value) { 

    $this->db->select('customer.*,membership.*');
        $this->db->from('customer');
        $this->db->join('membership', 'customer.id = membership.customer_id', 'left'); 
        $this->db->where('membership.customer_id', $value['customer_id']);
        $this->db->order_by('membership.customer_id','DESC');

        $this->db->limit('1');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $dataa = $query->result();

     foreach ($dataa as $values) {

            $date1 = new DateTime($todayDate);
            $date2 = new DateTime($values->end_date);

            $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
         $days =  $diff->format("%a"); 
         $pos =  $diff->format("%R");

        if($pos == "+" && $days >= 0){

            $item[] = $values;

        }         

    }
```

But it return all rows from both joined table. but i want only latest(last) rows with each customer id..!

Please tell me where i am going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get last record for each customer from membership table based on highest id you can do a self join to membership by tweaking the joining part like

```
$this->db->select('c.*,m.*');
$this->db->from('customer as c');
$this->db->join('membership as m', 'c.id = m.customer_id', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('membership as m1', 'm.customer_id = m1.customer_id AND m.id < m1.id', 'left'); 
$this->db->where('m1.id IS NULL', null, false)
$query = $this->db->get();
```

A plain SQL would be something like

```
SELECT c.*,m.*
FROM customer AS c 
LEFT JOIN membership AS m ON c.id = m.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN membership AS m1 ON m.customer_id = m1.customer_id 
               AND m.id < m1.id
WHERE m1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this :
`$dataa = $query->result();`
to this :
`$dataa = $query->row();`

Comment: its return error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Dont use foreach loop after that line, because it's already a single object, instead directly access it like: `$dataa->end_date`